# javascript Highcharts over option change backgroung color

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have 5 days trying to change color zone, this's code:

```
   [https://jsfiddle.net/gerarca/7sg1c4nz/187/][1]
```

I just want to change backgroung color on over event, like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRW7G.png)

If I put the mouse pointer over a department, an area should be highlighted in red, the area to which the department belongs.

I tried to do it using multiple overs, but this property can only be used once and don't work.

where I'm wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each department in your example refers to one point in the series. If you want to change the `colour` of the hovered point, you can use i.e `point.events` to achieve that:

```
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function() {
          originalColor = this.color;

          this.update({
            color: '#5F9EA0'
          });
        },
        mouseOut: function() {
          this.update({
            color: originalColor
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

But if you want to change the `colour` of the zones and enable the `dataLabels` on hover, as like image shows, it would be best to create zones as a separate series. Then you will be able to easily update these series after `mouseOver` event.

```
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
      chart: {
        map: topology
      },

      title: {
        text: ''
      },

      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            color: 'white',
            format: '{point.name}'
          },
          color: 'grey',
          allAreas: false,
          states: {
            hover: {
              color: 'red'
            }
          },
          events: {
            mouseOver: function() {
              this.update({
                color: 'red',
                dataLabels: {
                  enabled: true
                }
              }, false)
              chart.update({}, true, false, false);
            },
            mouseOut: function() {
              this.update({
                color: 'grey',
                dataLabels: {
                  enabled: false
                }
              }, false)
              chart.update({}, true, false, false);
            }
          }
        },
      },

      series: [{
          data: zone1,
          name: 'zone 1'
        },
        {
          data: zone2,
          name: 'zone 2'
        },
        {
          data: zone3,
          name: 'zone 3'
        },
        {
          data: zone4,
          name: 'zone 4'
        },
        {
          data: zone5,
          name: 'zone 5'
        }
      ]
    });
```

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/296ujzf4/

**API References:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.mouseOver
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css file:

```
.highcharts-series-group path:hover {
    fill: rgba(249, 209, 12, 0.87); // or whatever color
}
```